# SVG hover cancelled when mousing over an object on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an SVG that had to have text centred both horizontally and vertically.

I would have pasted an image but don't have enough rep points. You can see the graphic at

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tt9ayqr0xugr4m9/link_example.png?dl=0

I need the white around the text to go grey (#eeeeee) when you hover over it. I got that with some simple CSS. I even got it with jQuery and some SVG but the issue is that when you hover over the word **about** (which needs to stay black all the time), the grey goes back to white as the text is over the circle and cancels the hover. I have been trying for hours and hours to fix this.

My code is:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">

<!-- gradient information -->
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="100">

    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#ED7625"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#CF202F"/>

</linearGradient>

<a xlink:href="about.php">

    <!-- gradient -->
    <circle class="gradient-outer" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>

    <g class="svg-button_1">

        <!-- white overlay -->
        <circle id="#svg-text_1" class="white-inner" cx="50" cy="50" r="46" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="white" />

        <!-- text element -->

        <text x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle">About</text>

    </g>

</a>
```

Any help would be appreciated and I have tried many numerous ways with HTML/CSS/jquery to do it but it also have to be a link, scalable, ratio locked and responsive. (GROAN!!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/boqune/1/edit?html,css,output)

The jsbin has your required code. The issue you are facing is because

- Text is not inside circle. Create a svg group and make that effect on
  the svg group
- 2>One more point is dont give your id as # i.e `<circle
  id="#svg-text_1"` should be `<circle id="svg-text_1"`

  .svg-button_1:hover #svg-text_1{
        fill: grey;
      }

SVG is as below

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">

<!-- gradient information -->
<linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="100">

    <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#ED7625"/>
    <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#CF202F"/>

</linearGradient>

<a xlink:href="about.php">

    <!-- gradient -->
    <circle class="gradient-outer" fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>

    <g class="svg-button_1">

        <!-- white overlay -->
        <circle id="svg-text_1" class="white-inner" cx="50" cy="50" r="46" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="white" />

        <!-- text element -->

        <text x="50%" y="50%" dy=".3em" text-anchor="middle">About</text>

    </g>

</a>
```

Comment: OF COURSE!!!! That makes total sense. I knew it would be something simple. Thanks a bundle. I owe you a beer!